# Use or operator in constraint cvxpy

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am trying to use cvxpy but i don't know how to use or operator.

I have

`x = cp.Variable(N, integer=True)`

I try

`x[i]==0 or x>=m[i]`.

I got this error

```
> Cannot evaluate the truth value of a constraint or chain constraints, e.g., 1 >= x >= 0.
```

Then i try:

```
for i in range(N):
    constraints += [
        x[i]*(x[i]-m[i])>=0,
    ]
```

And i got

```
> Problem does not follow DCP rules.
```

Can someone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint

```
 x=0 or x≥L
```

is known as `x` being a semicontinuous variable. Some solvers and tools have specialized facilities for this. Otherwise, add a binary variable `y` and use:

```
 y*L ≤ x ≤ y*U
 x ∈ [0,U]        (U is an upperbound on x)
 y ∈ {0,1}
```

Comment: sorry. When I use 
`y = {0,1}; U = 99999999; 
x = cp.Variable(N, integer=True) ;
constraints = []; for i in range(N): constraints += [ ym[i]<= x[i]<=yU, ]` 
Error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'set' and 'int' 
And when I use: 
`y = cp.Variable(1, integer=True); constraints = [0 <= y, y <= 1]; U = 99999999; x = cp.Variable(N, integer=True); constraints = [];  for i in range(N):     constraints += [         y*m[i]<= x[i]<=y*U,     ]` Error: Cannot evaluate the truth value of a constraint or chain constraints. You have any idea for that?

Comment: Maybe surprisingly, a sandwich constraint like `x ≤ y ≤ z` can be split into two: `x ≤ y` and `y ≤ z`. Also you need `y[i]`,